# Тип поля float в модели Yii

Tags: yii

Здравствуйте. Gii генерирует все поля модели как string. В БД у меня поле DECIMAL. В результате например число 12.2 имеет вид 12.2000. У меня есть сгенерированный CRUD - нужно выводить без незначащих нулей. И еще в парочке мест. Обрезать число перед выводом уже не вариант - много мест. Как на уровне модели сделать, чтоб она хранила такое число в float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться поведением [afterFind()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterFind-detail)

```
protected function afterFind()
{
    parent::afterFind();
    $this->price = number_format($this->price, 2);
}
```

Comment: @Demyan112rv, ну я не знаю сколько незначащих нулей у меня. Придется вручную их убирать тогда. Но это уже решение конечно. Но сгенерированные модели Yii не умеют работать с float получается, везде строки?